# Is there any method or plug in to handle R packages in NetBeans

Tags: r, netbeans

I have created a NetBean GUI application.In that GUI i have added several menu items and i want to handle several statistical functions when clicking each menu items.For that purpose i need R plug in Netbeans such that I can easily link with R.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements there are different ways to do this, e.g. eval, link, pipe, socket or stub. I will write about these 5 methods here:

EVAL:

You can call R and pass in a script-file, R will evaluate the script and return the result of the statistical computation to the console.

(Please also tell us what operating-system you are running on, in the following I will just assume you are running on Windows)

If you have a file a.txt:

> 1+2

You can enter in the console cmd.exe:

> R.exe -f a.txt

LINK:

You link some C-code to the R-sources: this is probably not very interesting to you because Netbeans is written in Java and linking would be difficult.

PIPE:

This is the possiblity you would choose if you want to also use the R-GUI. The above console-eval-option only produces textual output but with this method you can (eventually) also produce graphics and transmit them to Netbeans. You use named pipes (again, i have to assume you are using Windows) which you can open on the R-side with the function pipe().

SOCKET:

analogues, but with the function socketConnection

STUB:

You write a DLL in e.g. C, load the DLL using dyn.load(), and call functions in it with the function .C(); in that DLL you can use e.g. a pipe or socket to communicate with Java.